# How to get linux kernel coredump for later analysis using gdb tool?

Tags: gdb, kernel, coredump, panic

Is it possible to intentionally crash the kernel at specific point during the course of its execution (by inserting some C statement there Or otherwise) and then collect the corefile for analysis using normal gdb program ?
Can somebody pls share the steps and what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to intentionally crash the kernel

Sure: just insert a call to `panic()` in desired place.

The easiest way to do this is using [user-mode linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/). The kernel becomes just a regular program, and you can execute it under GDB the usual way, setting breakpoints, looking at variables, etc.

If you need to do "bare metal" execution, you should probably start [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html) or [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html).

Comment: Actually, all i want to is to do live gdb on linux kernel code. But i dont get the idea how to accomplish this in my VMsetup.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097164/using-kgdboc-for-kernel-debugging

Request you pls take a look at this Ques by me, and help me out if you have any context, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anyways, i am taking a look at the UML if that resolves my problem.